# After using SecKeyGeneratePair, how can I access permissions on the resultant key?

Tags: cocoa

I am using SecKeyGeneratePair to create a pair of keys, but I cannot figure out how to set access controls. I want to set it so that the second time my app wants to use it, it doesn't ask the user for permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably too late, but anyway. Check out code sample in [Modifying the Access List of an Existing Keychain Item](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH205-BBCHEABI) topic of [Keychain Services Tasks for Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html) manual.

Also, if it was your application that created the keys, it should have access to them.

Comment: If I recall correctly, my problem ended up being differences on Snow Leopard and Lion. I ended up saving a reference after creation instead of trying to lookup the item on subsequent opens. I think your answer works also, so hopefully it helps someone in the future :)